# Win8 - Unhandled exception in Windows.UI.Xaml.dll

Tags: winapi, xaml, windows-8, unhandled-exception

I've got some strange behavior while debugging/running my metro app.
During drag'n'drop the screen will be refreshed. I'd added some functionality to block binded properties from refreshing while drag'n'drop is in progress.

But sometimes the app crash, but in stead of throwing some exception which I can debug, all I got is an window saying to open an external just-in-time-debugger

> An unhandled win32 exception occurred in SOME_APP.exe [7785].

(The external debugger does not bring more information)

And the output says:

> Unhandled exception at 0x05017145 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in SOME_APP.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000088.

I'm working on a x64 device.
Has somebody ever heard of such problem?

Comment: It gave you a perfectly good exception - Access violation. You're trying to access or modify memory that isn't yours.

Comment: yes, it seems to, but I don't do any memory addressing by code. Could there be some problems with win8, xaml.dll and/or 32bit system vs. 64bit?

Comment: I can't say for sure but my first test would be to comment out your code that disables refreshes and see if the error persists. You could, without knowing it, be corrupting memory somewhere in there which might lead to this error. This is all hypothetical though. If the error no longer happens with that code removed, you may want to post what exactly you're doing in there so we can look for errors.

Comment: What does the code do that disables bindings. Is the crash because the drag-and-drop operation is still in progress?

Comment: Just for info, it was a Bug in the release candidate (RC). The Drag and Drop in Lists is now working as expected.

Answer (score 11):

If you're passing objects implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, inherited BindableBase or DependencyObject etc. thru NavigationParameter; and bind then in the NavigatedPage (or binded them in the navigating page) you'll most likely get this error. Don't pass any object except primitive type thru NavigationParameter when navigating.

You are getting this exception because non-existent referenced methods. For example.

1. You have an object named Categories which inherites BindableBase.
2. You binded that to Home.xaml.
3. Home.xaml's binding mechanism subscribed the PropertyChanged event of Categories object.
4. You navigated the Article.xaml passing Categories object as a the NavigationParameter.
5. You binded the Categories object to Article.xaml.
6. When a property changes in Categories object; that property will fire PropertyChanged event.
7. There are two subscribers to that event. Home.xaml and Article.xaml, but Home.xaml is no longer exist since you navigated away from it. But your delegate holds the address of it; so it tries to Execute; and fail with Access violation error.